# A nice geometric inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $XYZ$ be a triangle with side lengths of the triangle as $a,b, c$. Consider, $o_a$, $o_b$, $o_c$ as the lengths of the medians of the medians of the triangle. Then, prove that -

$\frac{o_a o_b}{b^2 + c^2}$ $+$ $\frac{o_b o_c}{c^2 + a^2}$ $+$ $\frac{o_c o_a}{a^2 + b^2}$ $\leq$ $\frac{9}{8}$

**My Approach -**
I tried to use the following inequality but I was not able to get the answer
$$\left(\frac{m_a}{a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{m_b}{b}\right)^2+\left(\frac{m_c}{c}\right)^2\geq\frac{9}{4}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: i solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I was trying to use this median inequality -

Comment: $(\frac{m_a}{a})^2$ $+$  $(\frac{m_b}{b})^2$ $+$ $(\frac{m_c}{c})^2$ $\geq$ $\frac{9}{4}$

Comment: But I was not able to get the solution using it. I request you to please show me the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM twice we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{m_am_b}{b^2+c^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^2+c^2)m_am_b}{(a^2+c^2)(b^2+c^2)}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2}(a^2+c^2)\left(\frac{m_a^2}{(b^2+c^2)^2}+\frac{m_b^2}{(a^2+c^2)^2}\right)=$$
$$=\tfrac{1}{8(a^2+b^2+c^2)}\sum_{cyc}(a^2+c^2)\left(\tfrac{(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(b^2+c^2)^2}+\tfrac{(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a^2+c^2)^2}\right)\leq$$
$$\leq\tfrac{1}{32(a^2+b^2+c^2)}\sum_{cyc}(a^2+c^2)\left(\tfrac{(2b^2+2c^2-a^2+a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{(b^2+c^2)^2}+\tfrac{(2a^2+2c^2-b^2+a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{(a^2+c^2)^2}\right)=\frac{9}{8}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The hint.

There is a dualism between medians and sides of the triangle.

Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{m_b^2+m_c^2}\leq2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{4a^2+b^2+c^2}\leq\frac{1}{2},$$
which is true even for any positives $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Indeed, let $a=\min\{a,b,c\}$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+v$.

Thus, $u\geq0$, $v\geq0$ and we need to prove that:
$$48(u^2-uv+v^2)a^4+4(13u^3+9u^2v+13v^3)a^3+$$
$$+4(11u^4+2u^3v+27u^2v^2-7uv^3+11v^4)a^2+$$
$$+2(7u^5+12u^4v+10u^3v^2+22u^2v^3-3uv^4+7v^5)a+$$
$$+4u^6-2u^5v+21u^4v^2-10u^3v^3+21u^2v^4-8uv^5+4v^6\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Also, there is solution by AM-GM, but it's not mine.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you have written in the second cyclic summation. Could you please elaborate it further for me ??

Comment: Use $m_b=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}$

Comment: And similarly for $m_c$ ? And then we need to prove the second cyclic summation. Please tell if I am doing it correct ...

Comment: But how to prove the second cyclic summation ? I am sorry to disturb you once again but how to prove the second one ?

Comment: I am driving now. I'll back at home and I'll write a full proof.

Comment: Ok, Thank you ...

Comment: I think this is early to ask but when will you be posting the solution to this problem ?

Comment: You said that there is a solution by C-S. I request you to please show it as well